# Solution manual for " How to Prove it by D. Vellemen "

Tags: reference-request

I am solving this book. It has good exercises. Since i am new to proofs. Also i am doing every proof on my own but not sure if its correct. Writing single proof for checking on MSE takes lot of time. Is there any solution manual available for this book so that i can compare my proof with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, there are solutions to suggested exercises at the back of the book.

Nevertheless, you might also want to refer [here](https://www.inchmeal.io/htpi/ch-1/sec-1.3.html).

Comment: this is not official. i wonder if solutions are correct?